# Trigger Click when in Near Viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scroll, infinite-scroll

I have a *"Load More"* button which is at footer.

Now when i scroll my `body` and is *just above* `#loadSomeMoreCrap` i want to trigger `runthisfunction();`.

Can anyone help me figure this out. I went through JScroll but didnt find my answer. Any help would be great Thanks.

### HTML

```
<div id="PasteCrapHere"></div>
<button id="loadSomeMoreCrap">Load More</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#loadSomeMoreCrap').click(function(){
   runthisfunction();
});
function runthisfunction(){
  //something done here! none your'e business
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crude, but you can add whatever else you want:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var b = $('#btn1').offset().top;
  var s = $(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
  if (s > b)
    YourFunctionCallHere();
});

function YourFunctionCallHere() {
  /* Fill container until it no longer fits on screen */
  while ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $('#btn1').offset().top *.8) {
    $('#container').append(count + '<br>');
    count = count + 1;
  }
}

/* Initialize container with data */
window.count = 1;
$(function() {
  YourFunctionCallHere();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<button id="btn1">click me</button>
```

Comment: Can't create a fiddle, because it needs to be able to pull multiple html pages, which fiddle doesn't support.

Comment: I just need a damn `function` to run no html page puling

Comment: @DangerousProgrammer Here you go.  Pretty simple.

Comment: @DangerousProgrammer Updated answer with working example.  It's crude, but all you wanted was the function, so there it is.

Comment: @RobertMcKee apparently good manners seem an optional for someone.  thanks for your valid help